# Trouble understanding memoize implementation

Tags: javascript, memoization

How does answerKey[parameters] work? if Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) 
returns an array [157, 687], is answerKey[parameters] storing an array as key?

```
function memoize(mathProblem) {
  var answerKey = {};

  return function(){
    var parameters = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    if (answerKey[parameters]) {
      console.log('returning cached');
      return answerKey[parameters];
    } else {
      answerKey[parameters] = mathProblem.apply(this, arguments);

      return answerKey[parameters]
    }
  }
};

var multiply = function(a, b){
    return a*b;
}

var memoMultiply = memoize(multiply);

console.log(memoMultiply(157, 687));
=>
107859

console.log(memoMultiply(157, 687))
=>
returning cached
107859
```

Comment: No, it stringifies the array to use it as a property name

Comment: @Bergi it does not stringify the array it calls .toString()

Comment: @TomDDD: That's what I mean by "stringifying". Should've said "casts to a string".

Comment: @Bergi I was just clarifying alot of time `stringify` means `JSON.stringify` which produces a different string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The square bracket notation will convert an array into a string

```
var answerKey = {};
var params = [157, 687];
answerKey[params] = 107859;
answerKey['157,687']; // 107859
```

So yes, the key is the content of the array as a string. This is not great practice.

**EDIT REQUESTED**

In general I try to avoid depending on strings that are created from `Array.prototype.toString()` because it has some odd behavior

for example. Nested arrays are flattened

```
[2, [3, 4], 5].toString(); // '2,3,4,5'
```

This is losing information about the source array and is indistinguishable from

```
[2, 3, 4, 5].toString();
```

To get around issues like these I suggest passing the array through `JSON.stringify();`

```
JSON.stringify([2, [3, 4], 5]); // '[2,[3,4],5]'
JSON.stringify([2, 3, 4, 5]); // '[2,3,4,5]'
```

This example will work with `.toString();` but I think its a bad habit.

Comment: "*This is not great practice*" - why not? What would be a better approach?

Comment: array .toString() has odd behavior sometimes and will bite you later. Consider this `[2, [3, 4], 5].toString();` This yields the string `'2,3,4,5'`

Comment: @Bergi this might be ok to use in this instance when memoizing two numbers. Consider instead of storing the array directly wrapping it in `JSON.stringify(params);` this will yield a string that looks like the actual array and won't flatten it `[157, 687]`

Comment: Well, given that `mathproblem` sounds like it's a function that takes only plain numbers, not any arrays, as arguments, this seems fine. But I'm getting your point, and would love to see it in your answer.